# Array conversion nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I would like to transform the following array:

```
 let errors = [
   {
     field: "data.time",
     message: "less length than allowed"
   },
   {
     field: "data.time",
     message: "wrong format"
   },
   {
     field: "data.age",
     message: "too young"
   },
   { 
     field: "data.age",
     message: "not enough information"
   }
];
```

Into:

```
[
  { time: "less_length_than_allowed <br> wrong_format"},
  { age: "too_young <br> not_enough_information"},
]
```

I basically want to remove the string "data." for each field attribute. And then merge the array, with common field as the object key and the concatenation of messages for the value.

This is what i have so far:

```
var removedData = errors.map(item => {
   item.field = item.field.slice(5);
   return item
});

var computedErrors = _.chain(removedData).groupBy('field').value();
```

Comment: an FYI - your first script actually changes `errors` array as well

Comment: I don't mind if errors is getting modified :)

Comment: why are there underscores in the `time:` result but not in the `age:` result?

Comment: true I fixed the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` in plain js to return the following result.

```js
let errors = [{
  field: "data.time",
  message: "less length than allowed"
}, {
  field: "data.time",
  message: "wrong format"
}, {
  field: "data.age",
  message: "too young"
}, {
  field: "data.age",
  message: "not enough information"
}];

var o = {}
var result = errors.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var key = e.field.split('.')[1];
  var message = e.message.replace(/\s/g, '_');

  if (!o[key]) {
    o[key] = {[key]: message}
    r.push(o[key])
  } else {
    o[key][key] += ' <br> ' + message
  }
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `var key = [e.field.split('.')[1]];` ... shouldn't that be `var key = e.field.split('.')[1];`

Comment: also, `e.message` needs to have spaces replaced with `_` ... so `o[key] = {[key]: e.message.replace(/\s/g,'_');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
var age = [];
var time = [];
var removedData = errors.forEach(element => {
 if(element.field.contains('time')){ time.push(element.message); }
 if(element.field.contains('age')){ age.push(element.message); }
});

var removedData = {
 age: age.join('<br>'),
 time: time.join('<br>'),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let errors = [{
  field: "data.time",
  message: "less length than allowed"
}, {
  field: "data.time",
  message: "wrong format"
}, {
  field: "data.age",
  message: "too young"
}, {
  field: "data.age",
  message: "not enough information"
}];

var mappedData = errors.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
  let type = currentValue.field.split(/\./).pop(),
    message = currentValue.message.replace(/\s/g, "_")

  if (typeof result[type] === "undefined") {
    result[type] = message
  } else {
    result[type] += " <br> " + message;
  }

  return result;
}, {});

console.log(mappedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.chain(errors)
    .groupBy('field') // group errors by field
    .mapValues(function(items, key) { // iterate grouped arrays
        return _.chain(items)
            .map('message') // get message value from each item
            .join('<br>') // join messages
            .thru(function(str) {
                return _.set({}, key.replace(/data./g, ''), str); // transform to object
            })
            .value();
    })
    .values() // get object values
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const errors = [{"field":"data.time","message":"less length than allowed"},{"field":"data.time","message":"wrong format"},{"field":"data.age","message":"too young"},{"field":"data.age","message":"not enough information"}];

const result = _(errors)
  .groupBy(({ field }) => field.split('.')[1])
  .mapValues((group) => 
    group.map(({ message }) => _.snakeCase(message))
    .join(' <br> ')
  )
  .map((value, key) => ({ [key]: value }))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```